# IPython/ Jupyter download as PDF styling

Tags: pdf, latex, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Imagine editing a typical IPython (4.x) notebook, *notebook.ipynb*, in the Jupyter editor. The code, graphs, and markdown get rendered exactly how you like them when previewed in the browser.

But then you "Download as PDF via LaTeX" and get something slightly different:

1. A centered title/ date header has been added.
2. The font is now serif instead of sans serif.
3. Section headers are numbered.

I'd like to change the default output to be a little more "what you see is what you get". In particular: I don't want a title header; I don't want numbering on my section headers; and I want sans serif font (code blocks look better with sans IMHO). How can I do this using the LaTeX custom *template.tplx* files and/ or the *jupyter_nbconvert_config.py* configuration?

I don't mind having to use the `jupyter nbconvert` command, but my first choice would be a one-click solution from the browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264909/suppress-section-numberings-in-nbconvert-to-latex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to use a different latex template.
See this post for more details.

[Changing style of PDF-Latex output through IPython Notebook conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624401/changing-style-of-pdf-latex-output-through-ipython-notebook-conversion)

Basically, you will need to edit your tplx files in your `/nbconvert/templates/latex` directory.

I'm still learning latex, but I did manage to change my default font for my documents to San-Serif by using adding this `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` to my `article.tplx` file.

Like so:

```
((* block docclass *))
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\documentclass{article}
((* endblock docclass *))
```

Comment: This worked. But it only changes the styling for the markdown. How do you change it for the code cells?

Answer (score 3):

You can run the following on your notebook file from the command line (in the same directory):

```
ipython nbconvert --to latex notebook.ipynb
```

This will generate a tex file, which you can then open with a latex editor such as Texmaker. There you can edit the latex code to conform to any style you want (i.e. changing font, changing margins, changing numbering, etc.). Finally, convert the tex to pdf (most latex editors have tools for this).

Of course, this isn't an automated solution, but it allows for detailed changes and customization, so your final pdf comes out exactly as you want.

Comment: I have done this on macOS. I converted it to .tex and my system is using MacTex/LaTeXIT. I have opened the tex file in LaTeXIT and I see lots of stuff but nothing to do with fonts. All the content is barely readable in the first place. I can see part of a line I want to change the font for but how do I change the font?